# Why do we have [updates]?

Tags: discussion, tags, burnination-request

Updates can happen in almost any piece of software. Update this database (engine) or this database (entry). Update the (package) list or update the (file) list. It has very well-defined meaning but can be interpreted differently when different tags are applied in different contexts which isn't useful at all. Should we burninate?

Comment: I would agree with you here. [tag:updates] does seem kinda useless - we really only need to keep the [tag:upgrade] tag. Maybe we could have [tag:repository-update] added?

Comment: @RPiAwesomeness what is "repository-update"? And upgrade isn't a saint either.

Comment: I was kinda thinking along the lines of issues when adding a new repository. However, now that I think about it, that is kinda silly :P